# hosting in iis express as a subdomain due to shared cookie - vs gives error you must specify localHOST aS servername

Tags: iis-express

We currently a cookie based single sign on solution for multiple sites.

As far as I know to share cookie you have to use a subdomain instead of localhost. Otherwise the browser would ignore it.

However I get an error saying "you must specifiy localhost as your servername" when I try change the project url setting to my subdomain.

It only works if I manually add a entry in the applicationhosts.config.

Whats the eaSIEST way to write a script that will merge other develelopers config with mine?

Or even better is there a way around this limitation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

In visual studio 2013 the only way I can find is to keep  the project url as localhost: then set the start url to yoursubdomain.domain.com.

To add site entry to iis express you can run the folllowing as per scott hanselman blog http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" set site /site.name:MvcApplication18 /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:hanselman-w500']
```